# When does Jack of Fables spin off from Fables?

Tags: comics, suggested-order, vertigo-comics, fables-comics

No spoilers please.

I am currently reading *Fables* in trade paperback form. When do I need to start (planning for and) buying and reading *Jack of Fables*?

I.E when does the spin-off begin in relation to *Fables*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Great Fables Crossover" is between Fables #83–85, Jack of Fables #33–35 putting a spit around Fables #50.

I would suggest picking up "Jack of Fables v1 - The (Nearly) Great Escape" just after Fables: Wolves which collects Fables #48-51.

Comment: There was a preview of Jack of Fables in Fables #50, so this is right.

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_Fables):

> It shows the adventures of Jack Horner that take place after his exile from Fabletown in the Fables story-arc Jack Be Nimble (Fables #34 and #35).

Comment: The math doesn't quite work on that, there is a later crossover between Fables #83–85, Jack of Fables #33–35 putting a spit around Fables #50.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the stories or these comics in particular, but it's not uncommon for separate comic lines to not operate in a 1:1 time scale. 30 issues of time in comic A do not always equal 30 issues of time in comic B.